# Eclipse color theme plugin-how to export the default theme setting to a xml file?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In the Eclipse color theme plugin setting,I like the eclipse default theme as the follow image.
But now I want to change the background color base on the default setting. I know that I can import a theme by a xml-file,but the problem now is how to export the default theme setting as a xml-file, so that I can change the background color and import it.
I've found on the Eclipse color theme official website,there are some [themes that claimed to be "eclipse default"](http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/?list=all&q=eclipse%20default) but do not seem to be 100% Eclipse default.
Or maybe if there is an existing eclipse default theme xml-file in some website that I can download?
Thanks advanced.

[image]